# How to get Column list of Synonym in Oracle

Tags: oracle, synonym

I need to get column list of SYNONYMS in ORACLE. The table on which synonym is created is in other schema. Can anyone help me in this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all columns in Oracle in SYNONYMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088991/how-to-get-all-columns-in-oracle-in-synonyms)

Answer (score 2):

This will return a list of all synonyms in the db:

```
select * from DBA_SYNONYMS
order by synonym_name
```

This will return a list of synonyms with a 'like' name:

```
select * from DBA_SYNONYMS
where upper(synonym_name) like upper('%SYNONYM_NAME_HERE%')
order by synonym_name
```

Relevant column names in response:

```
SYNONYM_NAME  
TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that I use to see synonyms and their targets.
You will need `SELECT` privileges on `DBA_SYNONYMS` and `DBA_OBJECTS`.

```
select decode(owner, 'PUBLIC', 'PUBLIC SYNONYM', 'SYNONYM') as objtype,
       decode(owner, 'PUBLIC', '', owner) as objowner,
       synonym_name as objname,
       synonym_name || ' => ' ||
       case
         when db_link is null then '(' || (
           select o1.object_type from dba_objects o1 where o1.owner = table_owner and o1.object_name = table_name and o1.object_type in ('VIEW','TABLE','SYNONYM','SEQUENCE','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','PACKAGE','MATERIALIZED VIEW','JAVA CLASS','TYPE')
                  and not exists (select 1 from dba_objects o2 where o2.owner = o1.owner and o2.object_name = o1.object_name and o1.object_type = 'TABLE' and o2.object_type = 'MATERIALIZED VIEW')
         ) || ') ' || table_owner || '.' || table_name
         else decode(table_owner, null, '', table_owner || '.') || table_name || decode(db_link, null, '', '@' || db_link)
       end as objdesc
  from dba_synonyms
 where OWNER != 'PUBLIC'
 order by 1,2,3,4
```

It's a bit wordy, but it makes nice output like this:

```
OBJTYPE OBJOWNER    OBJNAME              OBJDESC
------- ----------- -------------------- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SYNONYM SYSTEM      PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE PRODUCT_USER_PROFILE => (TABLE) SYSTEM.SQLPLUS_PRODUCT_PROFILE
SYNONYM SYSTEM      TAB                  TAB => (VIEW) SYS.TAB
```

This is actually part of a larger query I use for finding objects of various types, hence some of the redundant information.

I filtered out `PUBLIC` because that is one huge list.

Answer (score 1):

it's never too late to respond

```sql
select * from all_tab_columns@&SYNONYM_DB_LINK
 where upper(table_name) like '&TARGET_TABLE_NAME'
 order by owner, table_name, column_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from all_tab_cols where table_name in 
(select  TABLE_NAME from all_synonyms where owner = <SCHEMA_NAME> )
```

Answer (score 0):

In OWNER is the synonym owner

```
select * from all_synonyms 
 where table_owner=upper(:table_owner) and table_name=upper(:table_name)
```

What do you mean under "Column list"?